# Join two queryset in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, annotate

I'm writing a view that returns this:

```json
[
    {
        "field_id" : 1,
        "stock" : [
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "total" : 3
            }
        ],
        "reserved" : [
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "total" : 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field_id" : 2,
        "stock" : [
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "total" : 2
            },
            {
                "size" : "PP",
                "total" : 2
            }
        ],
        "reserved" : [
            {
                "size" : "PP",
                "total" : 1
            },
            {
                "size" : "M",
                "total" : 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For this result, I used `values` and `annotation`(django orm):

```py
reserved = Reserved.objects.all().values("size").annotate(total=Count("size")).order_by("total")

stock = Stock.objects.filter(amount=0).values('size').annotate(total=Count('size')).order_by('total'))
```

It's ok for me, but I would like put the `reserved` queryset inside `stock`. Like this:

```json
[ 
    { 
        "field_id" : 1, 
        "stock" : [ 
            { 
                "size" : "M", 
                "total" : 3, 
                "reserved": 1 
            } 
        ], 
    }, 
    { 
        "field_id" : 2, 
        "stock" : [ 
            { 
                "size" : "M", 
                "total" : 2, 
                "reserved": 1 
 
            }, 
            { 
                "size" : "PP", 
                "total" : 2, 
                "reserved": 0 
            } 
        ], 
    } 
]
```

It's possibile? Reserved and Stock doesn't relationship.